# How to get around unsupported C++11 code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, c++03

The compiler at my school does not seem to support C++11 but I'm not sure how to get around this problem. I'm also not sure what's causing the last compiler error. I am attempting to compile on Linux with:

```
gcc -std=c++0x project2.cpp
```

The system does not recognize -std=c++11. Any ideas on how to get it to compile? Thank you!

```
#include <thread>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "time_functions.h"
using namespace std;

#define RING_BUFFER_SIZE 10
class lockled_ring_buffer_spsc
{
private:
    int write = 0;
    int read = 0;
    int size = RING_BUFFER_SIZE;
    string buffer[RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::mutex lock;
public:

    void push(string val)
    {
        lock.lock();
        buffer[write%size] = val;
        write++;
        lock.unlock();
    }

    string pop()
    {
        lock.lock();
        string ret = buffer[read%size];
        read++;
        lock.unlock();
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    lockled_ring_buffer_spsc queue;

    std::thread write_thread([&]() {
        start_timing();
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("p2-in.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {   
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                line += "\n";
                queue.push(line);
                cout << line << " in \n";
            }
            queue.push("EOF");


            myfile.close();
            stop_timing();


        }

    }  
    );
    std::thread read_thread([&]() {
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("p2-out.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
        myfile.clear();
        string tmp;
        while (1)
        {

            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                tmp=queue.pop();

                cout << tmp << "out \n";
                if (tmp._Equal("EOF"))
                    break;

                myfile << tmp;
            }
            else cout << "Unable to open file";
        }
        stop_timing();
        myfile.close();
    }  
    );

    write_thread.join();
    read_thread.join();
    cout << "Wall clock diffs:" << get_wall_clock_diff() << "\n";
    cout << "CPU time diffs:" << get_CPU_time_diff() << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Errors:

```
project2.cpp:14:14: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
project2.cpp:14:14: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘write’
project2.cpp:15:13: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
project2.cpp:15:13: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘read’
project2.cpp:16:13: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
project2.cpp:16:13: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘size’
project2.cpp: In lambda function:
project2.cpp:79:13: error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘_Equal’
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but avoid locking and unlocking mutex manually. Follow the RAII paradigm and use `std::unique_lock` or `std::lock_guard` instead. That way, you can't forget to unlock your mutex and you are protected from lock leaks in case of exception.

Comment: The error shown is easy, you just move the initialization to the constructors. But you are using the `<thread>` library, which is simply non-existent and can't be "fixed"

Comment: std::string has no member called _Equal in any standard you can use the == operator.

Comment: Did you try `g++` instead of `gcc`? What's your GCC version?

Comment: isn't gcc redirecting to g++ ? it seems so seeing the error message.

Comment: run `g++ -v` or `gcc -v` and tell us your gcc version. For example, when I run it, the last line shows `gcc version 4.8.5`. Your version is definitely much older than mine.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but you probably can't use C++11. The compiler version your school uses is *really* old. You could try to convince them to upgrade, but it's unlikely :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace

```
class lockled_ring_buffer_spsc
{
private:
    int write = 0;
    int read = 0;
    int size = RING_BUFFER_SIZE;
    string buffer[RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::mutex lock;
public:
```

by uninitialized members (except for the static array) + a default constructor

```
class lockled_ring_buffer_spsc
{
private:
    int write;
    int read;
    int size;
    string buffer[RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    //std::mutex lock;
public:
  lockled_ring_buffer_spsc() : write(0),read(0),size(RING_BUFFER_SIZE)
  {}
```

and

```
if (tmp._Equal("EOF"))
```

is simply

```
if (tmp == "EOF")
```

As someone noted, `std::mutex` only was introduced in C++ 11. You'll have to use plain C [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) / `pthread_mutex_unlock` functions for instance.

Comment: `std::mutex` is a c++11 feature.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux didn't see that error on the log, but you're right. I remember using `pthread` library when I was coding c++ 03 a looong time ago.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that your compiler does not complain about `std::mutex`, which is a C++11 feature, but complains about the other C++11 features.

The lines

```
int write = 0;
int read = 0;
int size = RING_BUFFER_SIZE;
```

are valid in C++11 but not prior versions. You can initialize them in a constructor.

```
class lockled_ring_buffer_spsc
{
private:
    int write;
    int read;
    int size;
    string buffer[RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::mutex lock;
public:
    lockled_ring_buffer_spsc() : write(0), read(0), size(RING_BUFFER_SIZE) {}

...

};
```

That will work as long as the compiler supports `std::mutex` in a pre-C++11 version. If that's not the case, you'll have to find a solution to that problem separately.